# Node passwordless sending dynamic body per token request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, password-less

I am trying to use the [passwordless library](https://github.com/florianheinemann/passwordless) in Node to send varying HTML/text bodies of the emails, depending on the situation.

Currently its all working perfectly as the examples show it to. What I want however is to be able to set the body of the email to a template depending on who is logging in.

I can already specify what delivery method to use, but I don't necessarily need a different delivery method, but to be able to pass another optional object to the `addDelivery` callback:

```
passwordless.addDelivery(
    function(tokenToSend, uidToSend, recipient, callback) {
        var message = {
            "html": emailText(true, tokenToSend, uidToSend),
            "text": emailText(false, tokenToSend, uidToSend),
            "subject": config.mandrill.subject,
            "from_email": config.mandrill.from,
            "from_name": config.mandrill.fromname,
```

If I could pass an object to that anonymous function, then I would be set. I basically would be able to pass in the message object

I think this would need to be passed in somehow from  `passwordless.requestToken`

```
passwordless.requestToken(
        function(email, delivery, callback) {
```

somewhere.

Anyone able to help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the object through [closures](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/). Basically, you can use variables outside the scope of anonymous functions. For instance, in your code you can do something like

```
var messageObject = ...;
passwordless.addDelivery(function(tokenToSend, uidToSend, recipient, callback) {
    message = messageObject;
    ...
```

Closures are really helpful, embrace them!

Comment: How is a closure different to a global variable in this example? (`passwordless.addDelivery` is not inside another funtion) From my "C" background, global variables should, if they can, be avoided. I am setting the value of messageObject in another file that calls upon `passwordless.requestToken` which inturn uses the delivery method setup when initialised

Comment: Global variables should be avoided. The scope of variables in closures on the other hand is limited. If for instance you would call addDelivery() from within a function, the variable available through the closure is only in the scope of this function. I am not familiar with the context of your code, maybe you can provide more information ? Using closures and variables like that in Javascript is extremely common though, and almost always the way to go.

Comment: Ok I thought so. I don't think then in my case I can use a closure that is within a scope. An example is here: https://github.com/florianheinemann/passwordless/tree/master/examples/simple-mail
In `app.js` you can see the addDelivery method being initialised. The value of the `text` property is set there. In `routes/index.js` you can see `passwordless.requestToken`. Its here that I want to be able to set the `text` property as this is "per user" rather than initialised at the outset. I was thinking to have a global `text` in index.js that is accessible from `app.js` - is that what you would do?

Comment: In the end, I had to go for a truly global variable: `GLOBAL.Message = {};` I really don;t like this solution, but I couldn't find a better way to read and write from a central object. Out of interest is this one global object for all users, or does each session get its own set of globals?

Comment: You just need to customize the email body depending on the username right ? I think the proper way is to look that up inside the function, like loading the appropriate template file for each user, or looking up the user details in a database etc. Would that work for you ? Also yes, the global variables solution is very ugly, and should be the same globally, although javascript's scoping rules make me unsure about this.

Comment: Yeah, instead of `message` i want to pass it all of the properties that make up `message` - i.e pass message in when I request a token, so that as you say I can pull details out of a database and the template is different for the user

Comment: Yes but the message depends on the username or the token right ? You can just lookup the message details in addDelivery for each username or token.

Comment: Ahh I see the confusion, I need more information passed to the message - for instance the body of the message is a user input. If addDelivery had access to `req` then I could do it. I want to be able to pass an object from the route to addDelivery - some of the data to fill the message isnt stored in a database, but is specified by the current user and passed as HTTP body parameters. A nasty solution would be to save it in the database before calling requestToken, and getting it out of the database in addDelivery - but seems extremely long winded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99228/discussion-between-amlwwalker-and-dtouch3d).